# finding reverse of a binary for a giving number using c

Tags: c

edit:

am trying to create a program that accept a number, shows its binary number and show the reverse of that binary. But i didnt know how to do it in a good way or ever in any way ~ so hopfully i can get help
this is my code:

```
    /*
 * C Program to Convert a Number Decimal System to Binary System using Recursion
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int convert(int);

int main()
{
    int dec, bin,reverse_bin,i;

    printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dec);
    bin = convert(dec);
    printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d.\n", dec, bin);
    for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
         reverse_bin =  bin << 1;

    }

         printf("The reverse binary of 10 is = %d \n",reverse_bin);
    return 0;
}

int convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2));

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse of a binary"?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Surely you don't "find" these things?  It is not a search problem.  "calculate" or "determine" perhaps? Your question is ambiguous; include example input and expected output to clarify.

Comment: Your `convert()` function returns an integer that when presented as a decimal contains only 1 and 0 digits.  It is a bad idea, mathmatically flawed and limited to 9 digits when an `int` requires 32.  The fact of teh matter is that an `int` *already is binary*, and converting its bits directly to a *string* makes a lot more sense.

Comment: `int convert_r(int dec, int acc)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        return acc;
    }
    else
    {
        return convert_r(dec / 2, dec % 2 + 10 * acc);

    }
}` , and at main `reverse_bin = convert_r(dec, 0);`

Comment: The `for` loop makes no sense.  The loop body executes 8 times, and each time through it performs the exact same assignment, which is to set `reverse_bin` to `bin << 1`, which is just `2*bin`.  Why?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : If you have an answer, post it as an answer.  SO comments are not the place for answers and are not suited to posting code.

Comment: @Clifford I thought I do not know well whether those required by the OP.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Fair enough; the question is ambiguous.  But in that case you should use the comment to request clarification rather than a way of posting an answer than cannot be down-voted.  Such clarification has already been requested, but the OP appears to be unwilling to engage.  I guess it was not that important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `convert()` function returns an integer that when presented as a decimal contains only 1 and 0 digits; that's a transform, not a conversion. It is a bad idea, mathematically flawed and limited to just 9 digits when an `int` requires 32.

The fact of the matter is that an int already is binary, and converting its bits directly to a string (forward or reverse) is simpler, and makes a lot more sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)
char* binary( char* buffer, int i ) ;
char* binary_reverse( char* buffer, int i ) ;


int main()
{
    int dec ;
    char binary_str[INT_BITS + 1] ;

    printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dec);

    printf("The binary of %d is %s.\n", dec, binary( binary_str, dec) ) ;
    printf("The reverse binary of %d is %s.\n", dec, binary_reverse( binary_str, dec) );

    return 0;
}

char* binary( char* buffer, int i )
{
    int b = 0;
    for( b = 0; b < INT_BITS; b++ )
    {
        unsigned mask = 1u << (INT_BITS - b - 1) ;
        buffer[b] = (i & mask) == 0 ? '0' : '1' ; 
    }
    buffer[b] = '\0' ;

    return buffer ;
}

char* binary_reverse( char* buffer, int i )
{
    int b = 0;
    for( b = 0; b < INT_BITS; b++ )
    {
        unsigned mask = 1u << b ;
        buffer[b] = (i & mask) == 0 ? '0' : '1' ; 
    }
    buffer[b] = '\0' ;

    return buffer ;
}
```

Note that the only difference between `binary()` and `binary_reverse()` is the calculation of `mask`.

Comment: Just to add that such operations are generally better only done on unsigned types. This because of the implementation-specific encoding of signed integers other than `intN_t`.

Comment: @Olaf :  I agree - but the OP's code used plain `int`.  To some extent however using a signed value serves a useful educational purpose in exposing how signed negative values are encoded.  The original code outputs sign+magnitude so that -255 outputs `-11111111` rather than the most likely actual encoding `11111111111111111111111100000001`

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I agree. for `i & mask`, `i` is first converted to `unsigned`. That is done in a way 2's complement value need no additional operation. This is not true for other encodings. So the result will always show 2's complement representation.

Comment: @Olaf :  OK... when you come across a system with another encoding let me know ;-)  .  It is in any case "educational" with respect to two's complement.

Comment: Some ADCs/DACs still use 1's complement or sign/magnitude, but agreed, that is normally converted before processing. About CPUs, IIRC, there was one of the larger accidents with space-equipment which had a problem with different encodings. Some time ago, but considering how old rad-hard hardware is, it is well possible there are still CPUs with alternative encodings being used. But acknowledged, these are pretty special fields. You can completely avoid such problems, though: use `intN_t`. These are guaranteed 2s complement with no padding bits.

Answer (score -1):

What makes your question hard is that it probably depends on the word length of your computer.  Simply put, does 0001 reverse to 1000 or 10000000 or 100000000000000000000000000000?  Well, let's just say it reverses to 1.  :)

If you agree to that, then the following should work:

```
int rb(int dec) {
  int ret=0;
  while (dec) {
     if (dec & 1) {
        ret<<=1;
        ret |=1;
        }
     else {
        ret<<=1;
        }
     dec>>=1;
     }
  return ret;
}
```

Oh, was there a goal to do it recursively?

Comment: You rely on implementation defined behaviour and invoke undefined behaviour for certain values.

Comment: thank you all for helping i think i got the answer i am looking for, it was with the calc function.. thanks and sorry am new here ..